# Do Differently Colored Poke Beans Have a Different Impact on Different Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I have Pokemon Ultra Sun and I use Poke Beans a lot but I am unsure of whether or not the colors or patterns of Poke Beans make a difference based on the Type or Species of Pokemon they are being fed to. If it does make a difference, is the same affect applied to Rainbow Beans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colours make no difference on the effect of a Poké Bean.

A patterned Poké Bean will increase affection more than a regular Poké Bean, while a Rainbow Poké Bean will increase affection even more. Patterned and Rainbow Poké Beans are also more effective when used in the various facilities on Poké Pelago.